# Почему кнопка не сдвигает текст?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>

Текст
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px
}

textarea {
    display: block;
}

input {
    float:right;
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

Почему кнопка submit не сдвигает текст, который находится ниже? Она ведь часть блока div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у неё прописано свойство float: right;

Это значит, что элемент выровнен по правой стороне и всё остальное содержимое блока на этом уровне обтекает элемент слева.

**Добавлено**. Если ж вы желаете сделать так, чтобы кнопка была справа, а текст - снизу, то нужно создать контейнер для кнопки и применить к нему CSS-свойство text-align. Оно определяет, по какой стороне будут выровнены все дочерние элементы контейнера.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <form>
        <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div id="other" align="right"><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
    </form>
</div>

Текст
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 350px
}
```

[image]

Вот рабочий вариант, float, видимо, работает не так, как вы хотите, [тут можно почитать как он работает](http://htmlbook.ru/css/float), а вообще используйте align.

Comment: Да ну, align устарел, как и все параметры оформления у тегов. Тогда уж надо использовать CSS-свойство text-align.